# how to return switch case value?

Tags: php, switch-statement

want return switch case values by selecting any option value.anyone help.thanks in advance.

```
<select id="product" name="product">
  <option value="28">at</option>
  <option value="1">Ac</option>
  <option value="3">bs</option>
</select>

<?php
$opt = $_POST['product'];
switch ($opt) {
    case "28":
        print_r(1);
        break;
    case "1":
        print_r(9);
        break;
    case "3":
        print_r(2);
        break;
}
echo $opt;
?>
```

Comment: As is, this doesn't make sense. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, you should probably be using [arrays](http://php.net/arrays). code would be easier to write an read.

Answer (score 0):

The form was missing.
Try with the below code - make sure you press the submit button and see if it shows your expected output.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="product" name="product">
        <option value="28">at</option>
        <option value="1">Ac</option>
        <option value="3">bs</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>




     <?php
        $opt =$_POST['product'];
        switch($opt){
            case "28":echo(1);break;     
            case "1":echo(9);break;  
            case "3":echo(2);break;
    }
        echo $opt;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your select should be a form (so it could be submitted to your php), wrap it like so:

```
<form method="post">
  <select id="product" name="product">
    <option value="28">at</option>
    <option value="1">Ac</option>
    <option value="3">bs</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

Now about your php; I don't know what you are trying with the `print_r` function but it's meant to print arrays and not integers.

```
<?php

$opt = $_POST['product']; // $opt is value that came from your html select

switch ($opt) {
    case "28": // if the value is 28
        echo(1); // you can do what you want, now i'm printing the value on screen            break;
    case "1": // else if the value is 1
        echo(9);
        break;
    case "3": // else if the value is 3
        echo(2);
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: this method give 1,28 result when is choose option 1. i mean 1 for echo and 28 for $opt. value can't change.

Comment: yes, like expected. if you choose 'at'  in your select, it has value 28. In your php you go through your switch and case '28' prints 1.  after switch you echo your $opt (28). Thats why you have 1  28 on your screen

Comment: i want result 1 only while i am choosing option1(28). what can i do. guide me.

Comment: just remove `echo $opt;`

Comment: $opt is variable. i could ask $opt value is 1 when i choose option1(28). product value is user input.get user input and want change my id depending on which value they select.

Comment: i edited my answer: added some comments. I hope you get it , else google "php switch"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="product" name="product">
        <option value="28">at</option>
        <option value="1">Ac</option>
        <option value="3">bs</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['product']))
{
   $opt =$_POST['product'];
   switch($opt){
     case "28":print_r(1);break;     
     case "1":print_r(9);break;  
     case "3":print_r(2);break;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this way to change the user input.it prints 1 to while i choose 28.

```
<?php
if($product=="28"){$product="1";}
else if($product=="1"){$product="9";}
else if($product=="3"){$product="8";}
?>
```